# how to solve a matrix equation like that

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

$$M^{T}MY + \lambda Y = D$$
M, Y, D are matrix, $\lambda$ is scalar value, Y and D have the same dimension.

M and D is known, how to solve Y.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

LHS is equivalent to $(M^T M + \lambda I) Y = D$

Comment: thanks! almost forgot those trick.

Comment: Note: a solution will uniquely exist for $\lambda > 0$.